# PostgreSQL Error 22012 devided by Zero after Truncate The Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

So after I truncated my table, this query which worked before, now doesn't work. Even I've already filled again my table, It still doesn't work. 
Here's my postgreSQL code :

```
SELECT 
                     k.reviewer                                               AS namareviewer
                     , COUNT(k.formcode)                                        AS actual
                     , ROUND((0.2*COUNT(k.formcode)))                           AS target
                     , SUM(CASE WHEN k.blibliknowledge != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blibli
                     , COUNT(CASE WHEN k.solusi != '' THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END) AS solusi
                     , ROUND(((COUNT(CASE WHEN k.solusi != '' THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END)+ SUM(CASE WHEN k.blibliknowledge != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) /ROUND((0.2*COUNT(k.formcode))))*100,2) as Percentage
                  FROM kpi k

                 GROUP
                    BY k.reviewer
```

And my KPI Table 
[image]

That data are the same with the first data which the query already worked. Why The error SQL state : 22012 devided by zero come up after the first table truncated? Thankyou in advanced :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULLIF` to avoid divide by zero error

```
....
, ROUND(((COUNT(CASE WHEN k.solusi != '' THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END)+ SUM(CASE WHEN k.blibliknowledge != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
   /NULLIF(ROUND((0.2*COUNT(k.formcode))))*100,2) ,0) as Percentage
........
```

**Complete code :**

```
SELECT
  k.reviewer AS namareviewer,
  COUNT(k.formcode) AS actual,
  ROUND((0.2 * COUNT(k.formcode))) AS target,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN k.blibliknowledge != '' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS blibli,
  COUNT(CASE
    WHEN k.solusi != '' THEN 'foo'
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS solusi,
  ROUND(((COUNT(CASE
    WHEN k.solusi != '' THEN 'foo'
    ELSE NULL
  END) + SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN
      k.blibliknowledge != '' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)) / NULLIF(ROUND((
  0.2 * COUNT(k.formcode))), 0)) * 100, 2) AS Percentage
FROM kpi k
GROUP BY k.reviewer
```

Comment: Could you give me the entire code? because after i attached your code, it still doesn't work because 'Syntax error' Thankyou :D